# Proving nilpotency class of certain subgroup is less than nilpotency class of group

Tags: group-theory, nilpotent-groups

Suppose $G$ is a nonabelian nilpotent group and let $x \in G$. I am trying to show that $\langle [G,G], x \rangle$ is a proper subgroup of $G$. If I can show that the nilpotency class of $\langle [G,G],x \rangle$ is less than the nilpotency class of $G$, why would this imply that the subgroup is proper?

To show that the nilpotency class of $\langle [G, G], x \rangle$ is less than that of $G$, I'm confused as to whether I should be looking at a central series or lower central series to proceed. I would appreciate any direction on how to approach this.

Comment: If the nilpotency class of $\langle [G,G],x\rangle$ is strictly less than the nilpotency class of $G$, then trivially $\langle [G,G],x\rangle\neq G$; I don't understand why you ask how this proves the subgroup is proper. That's like asking "if the order is smaller than the order of $G$, why is it a proper subgroup?"

Comment: Are you familiar with the result that in a nilpotent group, a subset $S$ generates $G$ if and only if the image of $S$ generates $G^{\rm ab}$?

Comment: You could prove that $\langle [G,G],x \rangle/[G,[G,G]]$ is abelian. That would proved that the nilpotency class of $\langle [G,G],x \rangle$ is less than that of $G$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $H=\langle[G,G],x\rangle$ and let
$$
1=Z_0(G)<Z_1(G)<\ldots<Z_s(G)=G
$$
be an upper central series of $G$.
Since
$$
[G,G]\leq Z_{s-1}(G)\cap H\leq Z_{s-1}(H)
$$
then $H/Z_{s-1}(H)$ is a cyclic group.
And so $Z_{s-1}(H)=H$.